# Pivot table based on frequency of elements in list column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a pandas DataFrame like below:

| List Values | Date |
| --- | --- |
| `[1, 2, 3, 4]` | 2022-07-17 |
| `[1, 3]` | 2022-06-17 |
| `[1, 4, 5]` | 2022-06-17 |
| `[2, 4, 1]` | 2022-06-17 |
| `[1, 3]` | 2022-05-17 |

The list contains unique elements so getting duplicate counts or conversion into a set would not be required.

I want to get a pivot table where the frequency of each element in list across month is derived, like below. The columns should be till month level (i.e. Year-Month):

| Value | 2022-05 | 2022-05 | 2022-05 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `1` | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| `2` | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| `3` | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| `4` | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| `5` | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and then use [`pd.crosstab()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas-crosstab):

```py
df = df.explode("List Values")

out = pd.crosstab(df["List Values"], df["Date"])
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
Date         2022-05-17  2022-06-17  2022-07-17
List Values                                    
1                     1           3           1
2                     0           1           1
3                     1           1           1
4                     0           2           1
5                     0           1           0
```

Comment: Just one small addition: I did `df['Date_Month'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('M')` before exploding as the output is month-wise